# Where should I keep data models in React and Redux?

Tags: reactjs, model, redux

In my app I have to make some order. Order has shape, about 20 properties, some of them are static, some are computed.

In my CartComponent.jsx i have method saveOrder which saves order for further use. **It uses plain object as order model.**

Now I can either confirm order or cancel it. After confirmation I dispatch authorizeOrder action to the store. Then user has to confirm order in some way (sms, token etc, whatever) and then order will be made. So flow is:
Save order -> Confirm order -> Authorize order (in other component) -> Send order (after authorization).

My question is: where should I keep shape of my order? It means - order model? Should it be created in authorizeOrder action? Or component is fine for that (sic!)? Or in orderModel.js which should expose order factory or order class?

Comment: Ok, so I decided to keep ma logic in separate directories inside module directory. I have module "payment" and there I created "models" directory (well... I cant find better name) and there I created "orderFactory.js" with one simple factory function which returns basic order or order with provided properties.

I can now use this factory as initial state for my reducer and moreover in my action creators to dispatch full order to the backend.

Thanks to that my reducers remain pure and action creators handle business logic (they add timestamp to the order, sort parameters etc).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `Redux`, why not keep it there?

`CreateOrder` will then accept parameters for the object to be created and added to the store in turn.

The `React` component should dispatch to `Redux` which feeds back to `React`.

So for example (if I understand the question correctly):

```
MyReactComponent = React.createElement({
...
saveOrder: function(e) { //assuming it is a button
     var myOrderObject = {
       //properties...
     }
     this.props.createOrder(myOrderObject);
}
.....
});

var mapStateToProps = function (state) {
    return {
        orders: state.orders
    };
}

var mapDispatchToProps = function (dispatch) {
    return {
        createOrder: function (properties) {
            dispatch(myService.create(properties));
        }
    }
};
module.exports = ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyReactComponent );
```

Next in the store, you create the object on the dispatch function with the key that compares to what you sent in the service

```
//myService
var load = function (data) {
    return function (dispatch, getState) {
        dispatch({
            type: "createOrderKey",
            payload: data
        });
    };
};
```

in your reducer

```
function updateReducer(state, action) {
    var newstate;
    switch (action.type) {
        case "createOrderKey:
            //clone state to newState
            //create and add the object
            return newstate;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: So your advice is to use redux. Ok. But what is myService? It looks like some kind of action creator, am I right?

Comment: Your service is basically a javascript file used to do either `dispatch` functions or talk to the server using, for example, `ajax` calls. Nothing special.

Comment: I have redux thunk to dispatch async actions (they handle comuncation with backend), but ok, in my project myService.js functionality is in actions.js ;)